# mercurial keywords not expanding in js and css files

Tags: mercurial

I am on Windows 7 using TortoiseHg 2.1.3 and I have configure it to use the keyword extension (please, no "it is bad practice" remarks, I have studied the arguments and I think in my case it is a valid use).
My mercurial.ini file looks like this:

```
[ui]
username = xxx
merge =beyondcompare3
ignore = ~/.hgignore

[tortoisehg]
vdiff =beyondcompare3
engmsg = True
ui.language = en

[extensions]
mercurial_keyring = 
keyword = 
convert = 

[keyword]
*.css =
*.js =
*.php =
*.html =
*.htaccess =

[keywordmaps]
Id = {file|basename} {rev}.{node|short} {date|utcdate} {author|user}
Revision = {desc}
```

Now in any php, html and htaccess file my $Id$ gets expanded as expected when I commit the file, but in any js and css file they do not?
I am at a loss as to understand why, in all files, the document header is the same (I use a template for that which has the $Id$ in it).

Answer (score 0):

Side note:
File-mask pattern for keyword section (and for other parts, where they used) must be **. (not Win-pattern with one star, but two). Sometimes for some filenames it can play

For the ID expansion I'll try probably to create clone of this keyword and test inside  problem file-types (don't forget kwshrink|kwexpand magic words), catch differences after tests